# Alloy Data Binding error after Alloy 1.8 Upgrade

Tags: data-binding, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

The Model:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        "columns": {
            "id":"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
            "title":"TEXT",
            "file":"TEXT UNIQUE",
            "desc":"TEXT",
            "media":"TEXT",
            "type":"TEXT"
        },
        "adapter": {
            "type": "sql",
            "collection_name": "downloads",
            "db_name":"downloads.db",
            "idAttribute":"id"
        }
    },

    extendModel : function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        });

        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection : function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

Note that the column `id` is `autoincrement`.

The View:

```
<ListItem title:text="{title} - {media}" subtitle:text="{desc}" itemId="{id}" />
```

Note that it's bound to the `id` column.

If I'm calling the following without specifying `id` (I don't have to. It's auto-incremented):

```
collection.create({title:'title',desc:'desc',file:'file',media:'media',type:'type'});
```

I get an error:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 10;
[ERROR] :      line = 4;
[ERROR] :      message = "Can't find variable: id";
[ERROR] :      stack = "anonymous\ntemplate@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/underscore.js:1:13899\nt@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/controllers/download.js:1:1326\ntrigger@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/backbone.js:1:1353\n_onModelEvent@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/backbone.js:1:9447\ntrigger@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/backbone.js:1:1441\nadd@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/backbone.js:1:6798\ncreate@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/alloy/backbone.js:1:8655\nfile:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7C3527BC-5AC3-4CF0-974D-58F4C5717601/FRCC.app/downloadmanager.js:1:481";
[ERROR] :  }
```

This is only after the upgrade. Any idea? A bug or something broken just from my end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit a bug. Hopefully the last one in a series of bugs we're solving in Alloy data binding. Please watch and follow progress as I'll be fixing this bug right.. now

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1477